# Grails each task in parallel

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I have a list of objects which I would like to call a method on for each but I would like this done in parallel.

I think this can be done by splitting the list and starting a number of threads, but in reading the Grails documentation there seems to be a better way but I cannot get it to work.

```
 import static grails.async.*

 def = a = {1,2,3,4,5}
 a.each{
     @DelegateAsync getPersonByNumber(it);
 }
```

This doesn't work
I have also tried

```
 import static grails.async.*

 def = a = {1,2,3,4,5}
 a.async.each{
     getPersonByNumber(it);
 }
```

This doesn't work ether.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: what exactly doesnt work? any exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GPARS for parallel execution. I used it some time back and it worked well for me.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/gpars

http://www.gpars.org/

Sample code:

```
public static int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 6

Closure executeMeInParallel = {
//Your execution code goes here....
 5.times {
   println it
 }
}

def f1 = null; def f2 = null; 
GParsExecutorsPool.withPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE) {
   f1 = executeMeInParallel.callAsync()
   f2 = executeMeInParallel.callAsync()                
}
f1.get()
f2.get()
```

Comment: Good answer but you cant use this with a list

Comment: You could do a.list instead of 5.times. I cannot try the code now but I think it should definitely work.